# What is the highest voltage currently in use for power transmission?

Tags: high-voltage, power-engineering

This is merely a question of idle curiosity that I hit a dead-end trying to research.

While the [Ekibastuz-Kokshetau high-voltage transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ekibastuz%E2%80%93Kokshetau_high-voltage_line&useskin=vector) famously<sup>[citation needed]</sup> holds the record for highest voltage ever used for power transmission (1.15 MV, if you're curious), it's currently (ever since the 1991 dissolution of the Soviet Union) being used at the more pedestrian transmission voltage of 500 kV. Are there any power transmission lines currently in use at voltages higher than 500 kV? What is the highest such voltage currently in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Are there any power transmission lines currently in use at voltages
> higher than 500 kV?*

800 kV DC is used by GE for transmission of power to islands and such like: -

[image: 800 kV DC is used by GE for transmission of power to islands and such like]

Words from [this GE brochure](https://resources.gegridsolutions.com/hvdc/hvdc-systems-brochure).

[Wikipedia - High-voltage direct current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current) suggest that 1. 1 MV is the highest used so far: -

> Most HVDC links use voltages between 100 kV and 800 kV. However, a
> 1,100 kV link in China was completed in 2019 over a distance of 3,300
> km (2,100 mi) with a power capacity of 12 GW.[5][6] With this
> dimension, intercontinental connections become possible which could
> help to deal with the fluctuations of wind power and photovoltaics.

However, in the next few years, that record is bound to be broken hence, this answer and your question will become out-dated.

Comment: Ooh, and you've made me realize I was wondering specifically about AC power transmission, not HVDC, but I never did say as much (so this is still a valid answer--if you can show that that's the highest, not just the highest used by GE).

Comment: @Hearth are we finished on this one now?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about it honestly.